# twig | accessing the index of an for loop in if-condition (add to string)

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I have the following problem:

There is a loop and I will use the index to check the record in a if-condition.

So the record has a name and a number at the end of the name ( I describe it as +i, but it is wrong ).

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
     {% if record.name+i>}

     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I have different content which I can get over
{{ record.name**1** }}
{{ record.name**2** }}
...

So how can I add the index of the loop to the end of record.name in the if-condition? How is the syntax.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: either `~` or [string-interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation)

Comment: no sorry, my misstake, it´s not a string. Its that record.name and than I want to add a number directly at the end of name.

Comment: maybe there is another, but you could always create a twig extension and do it on the PHP side. https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: `record["name#{i}"]`

Comment: thanks for the answers, Arleigh´s answer is working ;-)